# Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

convert array into `list`and that `list` convert to `arrayList`

```
    int[] array = new int[5];
    array[0] = 1;array[1] = 2;array[2] = 3;array[3] = 4;array[4] = 5;
    List list = Arrays.asList(array);
    ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
    alist =  (ArrayList) list;
```

Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Answer (score 3):

The class `Arrays` has its own `private static class ArrayList<E>` internally. It doesn't relate to `java.util.ArrayList` class. These classes are different.

It is likely that you are confused about this line in the source code:

```
return new ArrayList<>(a);
```

It is just a creation of nested class. There is no `java.util.ArrayList` import there.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays.asList returns an object of type java.util.Arrays$ArrayList but it is not extends ArrayList

just change the last two lines:

```
List alist = list;
```

and it will be fine